# How do I decrease the time required for a mongock script to acquire a lock?

Tags: mongock

We are running our mongock scripts in Kubernetes. Our service pod has replicas, so on initialization the first replica acquires the mongock lock while the second (and third) replicas wait their turn. The mongock locks work as expected -- only one script will run at a time -- but there is a gap in time between releasing the lock and the next execution acquiring it. In my tests, this gap was around 3 minutes. We have up to 30 replicas, so that will add considerable overhead to our pod's startup time.

This gap is 'dead time' -- i.e. our scripts aren't doing any work during it. I have verified in our logs that the first script execution has released the lock 3 minutes (or so) before the next replica acquires the lock.

There is a `maxWaitingForLockMinutes` setting in the driver documentation:
https://www.mongock.io/spring#building-time-driver

If I set that to a lower number (e.g. 1 minute), will that decrease the time the second execution waits to acquire the lock?

We have configured mongock using Spring annotations. I've added these properties to our Spring `application.properties` file (from the example from the mongock online docs) but it doesn't appear that mongock is reading them:

```
mongock:
  change-log-repository-name: myChangeLogCollectionName
  max-waiting-for-lock-minutes: 1
```

Is Spring application.properties the correct place for these?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `max-waiting-for-lock-minutes` has another meaning. I'll try to explain it:

If the lock is acquired for another process for 300secs, the mongock waiting for the lock will wait only those 300secs(plus half sec for margin). If the `max-waiting-for-lock-minutes` is greater, it won't use it, as it knows it will released earlier, so it's ignores.

However, if the `max-waiting-for-lock-minutes` is smaller, then an exception is thrown, as Mongock understand that you don't want that service to wait that long for a try.

So the suggested configuration is always the `max-waiting-for-lock-minutes` slightly greater than `Lock-acquired-for-minutes`, which minimum allowed value is 2 mins.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in a separated thread, an improvement in this area has been identified and will be provided in the version 5, which will be released around June. However, we'll be providing a BETA version with this improvement much sooner.